# Running cables through drainage, what is the best cable to use?

Tags: cables, waterproof

I have a project where we have been provided with cable routing through the water drainage and will therefore need to be suitably protected from being submerged in water fairly frequently.

What are the best cables to use for this, I am currently planning on using either H05VV-F or H05RN-F but is this going to give sufficient water protection?

Is it worth upgrading to H07RN-8-F or putting some conduit in?

Comment: Dig a tranch for the cable, you may not put it in a water drainage.

Comment: Trying to avoid digging a trench if possible, drainage is underground and there is limited space for underground services, is there any other way?

Comment: Submersible pumps for fish ponds use a rubber insulated cable if that's any use.

Comment: Polyurethane jacketed cables like [these](https://www.igus.com/product/?artnr=CF78-UL-05-04) are long-term submersible and fairly difficult to damage (within reason). I've also used neoprene jacketed cables with teflon inner insulation to a depth of over 100m in seawater.